# Get nested key by name

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have this structure:

```
const config = { modules: [ { debug: true }, { test: false } ] }
```

And I want a function that gives me the status of a module.
For example:

```
getStatus("debug")
```

With `config["modules"]` I get the array, but how do I return the value of a specific key in the nested objects?

`config["modules"][0]` would return `debug: true`
and `config["modules"][1]` would return `test: false`

How do I search for a key of an numbered index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bracket notation helps to reference object keys using a declared variable.

Assuming:

```
const config = { modules: [ { debug: true }, { test: false } ] }
```

This should work for your use case:

```
var getStatus = module => config.modules.filter(item => item.hasOwnProperty(module))[0][module];  
getStatus('debug'); // true
getStatus('test'); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call it like an object
    config["modules"] [0]["debug"]

If you don't know the index you can filter the array and 
   return the first one where debug is not undefined

```
var y = config["modules"].filter(x => x["debug"] != undefined)
return y[0]["debug" ]
```